# What is elastic thickness?

Tags: solid-state-physics, elasticity, solid-mechanics

I read the article about [Flexural rigidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexural_rigidity), it says Flexural rigidity of plates is defined as $D=\dfrac{Eh_e^3}{12(1-\nu^2)}$ and $E$ is the young's modulus, $\nu$ is poisson's ratio. And I can't find any description about elastic thickness. Can anyone tell me a definition of elastic thickness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the thickness of the plate.

From Landau's Theory of Elasticity, it is the $h$ in [Fig. 11.2](https://archive.org/stream/TheoryOfElasticity/LandauLifshitz-TheoryOfElasticity#page/n53/mode/2up), which you can see to correspond to your $h_e$ in the second footnote on [page 49](https://archive.org/stream/TheoryOfElasticity/LandauLifshitz-TheoryOfElasticity#page/n57/mode/2up/search/flexural+rigidity).

Answer (score 0):

it is the estimated thickness of the elastic plate to substitute for lithosphere in order to investigate **observed deformation.** It is also presented as Te (effective or equivalent).